# Trigger different for each notification button is being clicked

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating a media notification which needs to triggers different functions based on the clicked button. Is there any way to differentiate the buttons or do I need to create 4-5 separate Intents and PendingIntents? Here is the code which works but not exactly how is supposed to:

Edit: I added a new function which initializes new pending intents but here is the thing, when I press the play the playIntent is triggered but when I press the pause intent the playIntent is being triggered again.

```
 private void showNotification(boolean persistent) {
        String channel_id = "TEST_CHANNEL";
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
        );

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel testChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channel_id,
                    "TEST_CHANNEL",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            testChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);

            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(testChannel);
        }


        PendingIntent pauseIntent = initIntent("pause");
        PendingIntent playIntent = initIntent("play");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_remote_control)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_play_button, "Play", playIntent)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_round_pause_button, "Pause", pauseIntent)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_forward, "Title", null)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_back_left_arrow_circular_button, "Title", null)
                        .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())
                        .setOngoing(persistent)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);


        assert manager != null;
        manager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private PendingIntent initIntent(String action) {
        Intent tempIntent = new Intent(this, ActionReceiver.class);

        tempIntent.putExtra("action", action);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(tempIntent);


        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this,
                1,
                tempIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different pending intent for each action. Even though, you may use same class to handle all actions based on different action for each pending intent.

Comment: Please check the latest code, I did that but it still does not work

Comment: Please paste your ActionReceiver class. In ActionReceiver, you can differentiate based on "action" action string